# Bookmarks not getting created in PDF with xelatex

Tags: xetex, luatex

Please find following MWE.
It include all packages I've used along with 2 included pages and 2 bookmarks.
If I compile following code using **lualatex** its giving me bookmarks in final generated PDF file.
But, when I am using **xelatex** its giving me issue.

In log file its saying :-

***Package bookmark Warning: Missing parameter (bottom) for `FitV',
(bookmark)                using 0 on input line x.***

Above warning message appears for each  *\bookmark[view={FitV},dest=bookmark_208.1,level=0]... statement below.*
Am I missing any view related parameter here which have to be added if using **'xelatex'?**

I switched to xelatex because I am generating multiple documents with more than 40k pages for which lualatex capacity exceeded..somehow xelatex worked in this case.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,hidelinks,table]{memoir}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{lastpage}%
%
\usepackage{pdfpages}%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%
\usepackage{geometry}%
\geometry{a4paper,inner=12mm,outer=12mm,top=12.5mm,bottom=9mm,footskip=6mm}%
\pagestyle{fancy}%
\fancyhead{}%
\usepackage{hyperref}%
\hypersetup{pdfstartview={FitV}}%
\hypersetup{pdfremotestartview={FitV}}%
\hypersetup{pdfview={FitV}}%
\hypersetup{bookmarksopen=true}%
\hypersetup{bookmarksopenlevel=2}%
\usepackage[open,openlevel=2]{bookmark}%
\bookmarksetup{view=FitV}%
%
\begin{document}%
\normalsize%
\fancyhf{}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
\includepdf[pages=-,scale=.95,link=true,linkname=bookmark_208,linkfit=FitV,pagecommand={}]{/path/to/page/000001.pdf}%
\includepdf[pages=-,scale=.95,link=true,linkname=bookmark_209,linkfit=FitV,pagecommand={}]{/path/to/page/000002.pdf}%

\bookmark[view={FitV},dest=bookmark_208.1,level=0]{Cover Sheet}%
\bookmark[view={FitV},dest=bookmark_209.1,level=0]{Cover Sheet}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated but you shouldn't use fontenc,  inputenc, lmodern, textcomp with an unicode engine. I can't test the bookmark now, perhaps in a few hours.

Comment: Sure, I'll wait for your reply. :)

Comment: I've checked log using lualatex. That FitV warning is there too..but LuaLatex gives bookmarks in final pdf while xelatex dont

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the warning say, the FitV option expect a parameter, but bookmark/hyperref will use zero if it is not provided. But this is unrelated to the missing booksmarks: you are issuing the \bookmark commands after the last page, but with xelatex there must be on a page that is actually created. So move them before the \includepdf:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,hidelinks,table]{memoir}%
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[open,openlevel=2,atend]{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{view=FitV 0}%
\hypersetup{pdfstartview={FitV 0}}%
\hypersetup{pdfremotestartview={FitV 0}}%
\hypersetup{pdfview={FitV 0}}%
\hypersetup{bookmarksopen=true}%
\hypersetup{bookmarksopenlevel=2}%
\begin{document}%
\bookmark[view={FitV 0},dest=bookmark_208.1,level=0]{Cover Sheet}
\includepdf[pages=-,scale=.95,link=true,linkname=bookmark_208,linkfit=FitV 0,pagecommand={}]{example-image-a}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes..It worked like charm. Thank you very much :)